# adding new property to asp.net identity role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to add new property to asp.net identity role called Description. I wrote some code for that.

```
 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ApplicationRole() : base()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationRole(string name, string description) : base(name)
        {

            this.Description = description;
        }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

But I don't know how can I associate it with AspNetUsersRoles table. 
P.s I am using Asp.net mvc 5

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak there is not my question answer there

Comment: Your answer is there. The issue is that you haven't customized the RoleManager, and other Identity classes to use your custom role. The answers on that question detail how. Once you make the necessary changes, a migration will apply the requisite changes to the database to store this property.

Comment: See also: http://johnatten.com/2014/07/13/asp-net-identity-2-0-extending-identity-models-and-using-integer-keys-instead-of-strings/#Why-Does-ASP-NET-Identity-Use-String-Keys-in-the-First-Place-. It's focused on altering the primary keys of the Identity classes, but the same principles apply to adding additional properties as well.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for everything!